# How to hide the URL in the footer when printing in Chrome browser while retaining the page number

Tags: google-chrome, printing

How to hide the URL in the footer when printing in Chrome browser while retaining the page number.Just hide the URL.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HgAbu.png)

I tried to find the answer through ChatGPT.

In Google Chrome, you can set page headers and footers for printing by using the following steps:

Click on the three dots in the upper right corner of the Chrome browser to open the menu.
Select "Print" from the menu.
Click on "More Settings" to expand the options.
Scroll down to "Headers and Footers" and select the option you want (e.g. "Blank", "Date", "URL", etc.).
Make any other desired adjustments to the print settings, then click "Print".

But it doesn't work.

Comment: I don't think you can do that. It's a browser setting, not page setting.